# Does Stream skip loads everything in memory

Tags: java, memory, bufferedreader, java-stream

I have `Stream<String> s = bufferedReader.lines();`

The bufferedReader returns a lazy stream.

While using s.skip(100).limit(100) does it call to load all s in memory or it would be evaluated upto skip and limit value.

What would be memory footprint for using the skip/limit function?

Comment: The point of a Stream is that it doesn’t keep any more state than it needs.  Unless you call a method like [sorted](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#sorted--), the Stream won’t keep skipped lines in memory.  The limit is just a counter that by itself does not require anything other than the count to be retained.

Answer (score 2):

In order to skip *100 lines*, it’s unavoidable to read the data into memory in order to find the locations of the line terminators to know to which character position to skip.

Still, the memory footprint does not depend on the number of the skipped lines, as the size of the `BufferedReader`’s internal buffer will be fixed at the `BufferedReader`’s construction, see [`BufferedReader(Reader)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#BufferedReader-java.io.Reader-) and [`BufferedReader(Reader, int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#BufferedReader-java.io.Reader-int-).

As a corner case, if a line doesn’t fit into the buffer (note that the default buffer size is `8192`), a temporary `StringBuffer` will be used for that line.

Generally, there is no dedicated *skip* operation in the backends which the Stream API could exploit, which you can verify by looking at the [`Spliterator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/?java/util/Spliterator.html) interface, so skipping lines is not different to repeatedly invoking `readLine()` on the `BufferedReader`, but dropping the resulting strings immediately.

As explained at the beginning, reading the data is unavoidable, so the cost of creating temporary string instances from the read data is negligible compared to the reading itself.